# PostgreSQL : permission denied to select from foreign table in security mode?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

facing issue of permission denied to select from foreign table in security mode ?

[image]

1. I TRIED TO ASSIGN USER SAME ROLE AS DBADMIN.
2. I tried to assign permission on given schema, table
3. granted permission on all schema/specific schema
4. granted permission on all tables/specific table

The user mapping between local user and foreign server user can be done with **AK/PK** ? or it is required to use with **username** and **password** only

Still getting similar errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr